# Python's zipfile library can't extract password protected file

Tags: python, encryption, passwords, compression, python-zipfile

For some reason, Python's `zipfile` library cannot extract the files in [this password-protected zipfile archive](https://www.dropbox.com/s/trv44rgbgp4mhyl/extract_public_2018_20201006094007483_71129_20201001-20201006Texas.zip?dl=0). Here is the code I used:

```
import zipfile

zip_filename = 'extract_public_2018_20201006094007483_71129_20201001-20201006Texas.zip'

zipfile_password = b'&CkN52mKji3R8^4aI#7Z'

with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename) as myzip:
    myzip.extractall(pwd=zipfile_password)
```

This is the error I get: `NotImplementedError: That compression method is not supported`

I dug a little deeper and found that the compression method for the files inside this archive is 99. Where can I find what this compression method really is? And does this just mean I can't unzip this file using Python's `zipfile` librabry?

I'm using Python 3.8.

Comment: Yeah it looks like the compression of the zip file cant be unpacked with `zipfile`.
Do you have to use that library?

Comment: Not really, I'd be open to using any other library that is easily accessible in Anaconda. Do you have any suggestions? My current (incredibly dirty) workaround is to call 7zip using a command-line call with the `subprocess` library.

Comment: Try `py7zr` with `pip install py7zr`. Make sure to use that command in anaconda.

Comment: `py7zr` didn't work either. Here's the error I got: `Bad7zFile: not a 7z file`.

Comment: Mhm I am not sure what to do in this case. My knowledge doesnt help any further then this. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PKWare's appnote](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) says that 99 is:

> 99 - AE-x encryption marker (see APPENDIX E)

...

> APPENDIX E - AE-x encryption marker
>
> ---
>
> E.1 AE-x defines an alternate password-based encryption method used  in ZIP files that is based on a file encryption utility
> developed by  Dr. Brian Gladman.  Information on Dr. Gladman's method
> is available at
>
> http://www.gladman.me.uk/cryptography_technology/fileencrypt/

I'm guessing there are no libraries to help with that. You're probably stuck using 7z or PKZIP.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was guessing too =/ Thanks for the info, though!!!!